# Loading a file not working

Tags: java, load, java.util.scanner

Why doesn't `String m` get the string that is contained in the saved file?

It is the only thing in the saved file. I need it because it is a date string which I would then split into three integers: day, month and year.

```
public void load(){     
    try{
        Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(new File("SimpleDateSave"));
        String m = fileReader.next();

        fileReader.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException error){
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }
}
```

Comment: When something like this happens it is often helpful to see what value IS being placed in 'm', either using your IDE's debugger or just `System.out.println("m=" + m);`

Answer (score 1):

Use `m.nextLine()` instead of `m.next()`. `next()` only pulls in a word at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You put to `m` only first next part from your file.

Accord to your code:

```
String m = fileReader.next();
```

If your file contains white space at lines. For example as here - `13 02 1988`.
It takes only first number => `m = 13` And rest will be omitted.

You have few solution to solve this:

- use while() loop with condition:

  ```
  while (fileReader.hasNext()) {    
      // do smt with fileReader   
  }
  ```
- or use `nextLine()` instead of next(). 
  It takes all line before the end of line(this probably depends from your OS). You can read at [Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) more about it.